# Flash Builder 4.7 Not Air: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Building an app using SDK 4.5.1. (Never upgraded to 4.6 because of a bug in the way it manages runtime style changes.)

Just installed Flash Builder 4.7. Created a new workspace. Imported the existing projects, got this runtime error:

> VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code.

This is a Web app, not an Air app.

After I dismiss the error message and wait several seconds, I get another dialog. This one asks:

> "Where is the debugger or host application running?"

I deleted the project in Flash Builder, then deleted all the project files, and created a new project in Flash Builder with the existing code. Same result. Reinstalled Flash debug player - no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out (with the help of [this post on a Flexmojos list](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/FLEXMOJOS-314)).

Because we're using the 4.5.1 SDK, but also using JSON, we need to import an updated playerglobal.swc. I downloaded the latest from Adobe and used it, and failed to notice that it is not named correctly.

As downloaded, the file name is playerglobabal11_7.swc.

I renamed it to playerglobal.swc (i.e. took off the "11_7") and that fixed it. Our app now compiles and runs without issue.